# python average array when value are over a threshold (average if)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, mean

I have a 1D array and I want to get the average for all value which are more than a certain threshold. In excel the equivalent would be

```
 = AVERAGEIF(range,">6")
```

In python, I came up with this lines which works fine, but i was wondering if there is a nicer way to write it

```
a = np.array([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
indice = 6
b = sum(i for i in a if i > indice)/sum(a > indice)
print b
>>> 8.0
```

If there any smarter way to do this, or using some numpy function?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just write a function for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask invalid values and compute the mean on the masked array:

```
>>> np.ma.masked_where(a <= 6, a).mean()
8.0
```

The masked array is useful if you want to do other things with the mask. Alternatively, you could just filter beforehand:

```
>>> a[a > 6].mean()
8
```

Comment: Way simpler than my solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

This is not the most straightforward way (@coldspeed's answer takes care of that), but I was trying to think of alternatives just for fun. Use `np.average`, setting the weights to the boolean array from `a > 6`:

```
>>> np.average(a, weights=a>6)
8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, yours is more straightforward though! I also timed it, and the `np.average` is a bit slower on large arrays.

Comment: Good to have a second method. At least i learn about the weight parameter today.